# Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider' from assembly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I am getting this error in .net core installed annotation 4.0 version But It is Not Working How can I Solve This error.

> Could not load type

`'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.AssociatedMetadataTypeTypeDescriptionProvider' from assembly 'System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations,  Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'`

thank you.

Comment: have you tried to install from nuget?

Comment: installed From nu get but its not working

Comment: Then might be VS  not installed properly